# Cannot see schema information of a sql server - Connecting from R

Tags: r, sql-server

I open a connection through `RJDBC` to a sql server 2017 from R. I need to read data from views that other sw created for me.
I connected successfully with:

```
 drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
              "C:/Users/io/Downloads/mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar") 
  conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://sqlservername", 
                    user="user", password="user!",port=1170)
```

Then when I try from R

```
     sqlText <- "
                   SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables ;

            "
  queryResults <- dbGetQuery(conn, sqlText)
```

It returns me just tables for one particular schema.

If I run the same query

```
 SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables ;
```

from DbVisualizer it returns me all the schema with all the tables.

**UPDATE**

Tables i want to read are under `CRMIntegration` catalog while it seems that the tables that i can read from R are under `master` catalog.

[image]

Comment: ?? what's the difference with my question?

Comment: Obviously I put in commas in R. See my edited questions

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the same database in both cases.  Each database has its own catalog.  SQL Server also has "Catalog Security" so different users might see different tables.

Comment: How can i specify the correct catalog when connecting from R?

Comment: In JDBC you dry the databaseName parameter in the connection URL.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks that helped me to solve